# How to add a nested submenu in metroui

Tags: css, metro-ui-css

How to add a submenu within a submenu in the sidebar control of MetroUI.
For example:-

```
MainMenu
 -SubMenu1
  -SubMenu1.1
  -SubMenu1.2
  -SubMenu1.3
 -SubMenu2
  -SubMenu2.1
  -SubMenu2.2
  -SubMenu2.3
 -SubMenu3
  -SubMenu3.1
  -SubMenu3.2
  -SubMenu3.3
```